# Mono not working on OSX

Tags: macos, mono

I have installed the latest version of mono from http://www.mono-project.com/download/ (v4.6.1.5 at time of writing) onto OSX Sierra (10.12)

In terminal I have run `mono --version` and get a result of `-bash: mono: command not found`.

`which mono` and `which mcs` both yield no results.

I have restarted after the installation and get the same result.

I have looked in the installation folder and I can see the framework has been installed:

- **/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.6.1**
- **/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current** (symlink to 4.6.1 folder)

This is a clean installation of OSX. I have only installed Chrome, Dropbox and Skype over the original OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mono installed on Mac, but not recognized in terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542535/mono-installed-on-mac-but-not-recognized-in-terminal)

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover - this was the case on my 1st post earlier this week, on another mac, but this is a Clean Installation.

Comment: Is there a `mono` in `/usr/local/bin`? Do you even have a `/usr/local/bin` directory? Is `/usr/local/bin` included in your path?

Comment: I do have a `/usr/local` folder but nothing in there - no `/usr/local/bin` either

Comment: macOS clean install.... create the bin dir, symlink `mono` to there from `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current`, and add that bin dir to your path....

Comment: Are you saying I should be reinstalling the operating system again? :-(

Comment: No.... just add the `bin` dir.

Comment: "Recent" changes in OS-X/macOS no longer creates the /usr/local/bin by default. directory.... you can always add mono's `Current` dir to your path. But you will find out that a lot of other 3rd-party software require the local bin directory also....

Comment: OK then add a `mono` symlink from the `/usr/local/bin` folder into the `Current` symlink?

Comment: Yep, that would work. ;-)

Comment: That didn't work. Added the symlink (alias) that points `/usr/local/bin/mono` to `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current`. Restarted terminal, and rebooted. I still get nothing for `which mono` and an error for `mono --version`.

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem on my Macbook Air which I upgraded to Sierra

Comment: @Sam I ended up regressing back a previous version of Mono - that was OK for my needs. https://download.mono-project.com/archive/

Comment: Thanks @MarkCooper exactly how old version did you have to go back to?

Comment: @Sam - I've posted the details of my findings in an answer below. I'd be interested to know if you find the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a bug with Xamarin regarding this: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45574. As of time of writing there has been no response to this ticket.

**In summary:**
I have had to revert back to a previous release.
v4.4.2 didn't work either so I went back to v4.3.2
(from https://download.mono-project.com/archive/).

---

I don't know if this bug is view-able publicly, so the details are as follows;

> I am installing Mono v4.6.1.3 on a clean (brand-new) instance of OSX
>   Sierra (Virtual Machine). There is no other software installed other
>   than that included the OSX Sierra. I have not run any security
>   updates.
>
> Prior to installation:
>   - I have enabled viewing of hidden files
>   - I have downloaded the 4.6.1.3 installer from http://www.mono-project.com/download/
>   - The folder `/usr/local/bin` exists (See [1] on attachement)
>
> I have successfully run the installation package choosing all the
>   default options (See [2] on attachment)
>
> No files or links have been created in the `/usr/local/bin` folder
>
> From the command line;
>   - `mono --version` throws an error: `-bash: mono: command not found`
>   - `which mono` returns nothing (see [3] on attachment)
>
> I have to change folders to get this working:
>   - `cd /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`
>   - `./mono --version` returns: "Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.1 (mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/abb06f1 Fri Sep 23 19:24:23 EDT 2016)"
>
> ---
>
> This is different behaviour to previous versions, for example;
>
> Restored VM to "clean" state
>   - Installed v4.2.4 Mono package (downloaded from http://download.mono-project.com/archive/)
>   - The `/usr/local/bin` folder is populated with links during installation
>
> Once the 4.2.4 installer has completed I can successfully run the
>   following without changing folders (i.e. from `/Users/Username`);
>   - `mono --version` from terminal returns: "Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.4 (explicit/71b88f3 Thu May  5 17:25:51 EDT 2016) Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors.
>   www.mono-project.com"
>   - `which mono` returns "/usr/local/bin/mono"

Answer (score 2):

Just add /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands at the end of your PATH, no need then to set up any symlinks. Of course this should be done automatically for you during installation...