# Having trouble with installing Mono on macOS Sierra

Tags: visual-studio, f#, mono

I downloaded the package from www.mono-project.com/download/ and installed it without any problems. To check if I've installed it correctly, I did what the users in [the older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542535/how-to-install-mono-on-macos-so-mono-works-in-terminal) said I should do about this matter.

I ran the following commands in the terminal:

```
$ which mono
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin//mono

$ which mcs
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin//mcs
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 5.2.0.215 (d15-3/da80840 Thu Jul 20 16:43:07 EDT 2017)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-master/8b1520c)
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

Yet when I try to run some code on Visual Studio Code, I get the following error:

> Failed to start language services. Please check if mono is in PATH

So I checked my path:

```
 $ echo $PATH    
 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/:/Users/Steve/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Users/Steve/Desktop/nand2tetris/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/:/usr/local/mono/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

I have no trouble running F# in the terminal, so I know it's properly installed.

Any suggestions how I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to set both `"FSharp.monoPath"` and `"FSharp.fsiFilePath"` in users settings. Try adding following lines to `settings.json`:

```
"FSharp.fsiFilePath": "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/fsharpi",
"FSharp.toolsDirPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands",
```

Please, note that `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands` is the right path to Mono commands in latest releases.