# Can't run F# on mac with atom says 'usr/bin could not be spawned'

Tags: macos, f#, atom-editor, f#-interactive, ionide

I don't know what to do, SO is my last chance. Been trying to install Mono on my MacBook Air 2017 to run F# on an IDE such as Atom or SublimeText 3, neither works.

I need to be prepared for my data science studies where we need F# on an IDE. Preferebly Atom.

Mono is installed to: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.14.0 on my Macintosh HD, not under my userprofile. Perhaps that was the problem, but I tried installing mono to my userprofile folder and still the problem persist. I get the following error in Atom:

[image]

I've tried everything, followed [How to install Mono on macOS so mono works in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542535/how-to-install-mono-on-macos-so-mono-works-in-terminal) but thats not the problem, I can make it work in terminal, I just can't make Atom's ionide package

Really hope someone here is on a mac and sits with F# and know what to do.. Thanks for reading

Comment: Short version: Use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) instead of Atom. The Ionide dev team have all switched to VS Code, and the Atom plugin for Ionide is basically unmaintained. I suspect that the Ionide plugin for VS Code should just work for you.

Comment: or Visual Studio for Mac which is also great and is receiving a lot of fixes lately: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/commits/master (look at all those [F#] commits!)